# Individual level prediction of a person’s probability of voting without their vote history

Tags: self-study, logistic, missing-data, predictor

Is it possible to create individual level predictions of a voter's probability of voting when you do not know their vote history? In the data set provided in my homework assignment, I am given data on a number of people.  Some have a known voting history and some have missing values within the variable (these are the people the people without known voting histories).  The voting history is labeled `voted` with binary values (0,1) and the unknown vote histories show up as missing values (in stata: `.`).  I am also provided with other variables in the data set such as sex, age, income level, labor force, and race. I have tried replacing the missing values and running a logistic regression against all of the other independent variables such as sex, race, age, income, level and it has not worked.

*UPDATE: What I have tried thus far:*
I have also tried to create a new variable with just the missing variables in an attempt to isolate the people who have no vote history to make the problem easier but that also has not worked.

Comment: This is essentially the same as your previous question, which was closed (IIRC). "How do you..." is too broad to be answerable. Please take our [tour](http://stats.stackexchange.com/about) to familiarize yourself w/ our site. Then you will want to read some of our [materials](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for asking good questions on CV. Re: "Am I even on the right track...", unfortunately, probably not; you need a response variable for LR & your difficulty is you don't have 1.

Comment: Yes, it is a class assignment. Is the question still to broad? I'm still trying to figure out how to properly work the question without breaking the rules.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I think your question is answerable now. I have nominated it for re-opening.

Comment: Bear in mind that although we welcome HW questions, we treat them differently. Please tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you are stuck, & we'll try to provide hints to get you unstuck. To better understand the process, you should read the [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) for the `[self-study]` tag.

Comment: I edited the question again to include the different ways I have attempted to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may want to ask your professor, or whoever gave this assignment, what they have in mind.  It shouldn't really be a mystery.  There are very few 'trick' questions.  I don't know for sure what the idea is, but I think I can guess.  In addition, remember that we are giving hints here.*

There are a number of ways of dealing with missing data in statistics, such as [imputation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imputation_%28statistics%29).  However, I doubt that's what they're after here.  What would you do if you set those data aside, and fit a model to the data for which you knew the voting history?

Comment: Wouldn't performing a logistic regression and using margins to predict probabilities, just give me the probabilities for the people with known vote histories?

Comment: Leave the people w/ unknown voting histories completely out of it for the moment. What would you do if you only had the people w/ full data?

Comment: I would try to figure out the probability those people with full data voting for the next election.

Comment: So if you have a predictive model, & then later you came across some data where you had the requisite $X$ values, but didn't have the corresponding $Y$ values, how would you go about making an educated guess at what the missing $Y$ values might be?

Comment: I'm not sure. Perhaps run a linear prediction

Comment: Think about it: you have a model predicting $Y$ from $X$. Now you have some new data that presumably follows the same pattern, & where you have $X$ but not $Y$. You want to make an educated guess about the unknown value of $Y$. How could you do that?

Comment: I would run a simple regression and use the values of x to predict the new values of y.

Comment: First of all, your predictive model is a *logistic regression*, according to what you stated above. Second, how would you "run" a new regression if you didn't have Y values?

Comment: Okay, sorry, I'm really struggling with this. If I my predictive model is a logistic regression then to make an educated guess about the unknown Y value I would plug in my values into the logistic regression equation

Comment: Hmmm, that does seem like a reasonable thing to try. Can you summarize your plan of action now?

Comment: Pertaining to the Voting history problem, I would run a logistic regression with the complete data of the known voters and create a predictive model. Then using the model's equation, use the survey data of the unknown voting history people and plug in that data to get an estimated guess for the unknown voters.

Comment: Do you have any more questions about this? If your issues have been resolved, you may want to accept this by clicking the check mark below the vote total to the left (you can't vote yet until your reputation is >15, I think). Feel free to post additional questions on CV in the future.

Comment: I have no further questions. Thank you so much for bearing with me and helping me out. I really appreciate it.